# Java double to INDArray loses precision

Tags: java, precision, nd4j

I cannot convert double to Nd4j.INDArray without losing precision.

```
double[] weight = new double[]{-0.13404223866376802,-0.11294084872465669,0.11232944517596409,-0.01687720880184701,0.13288394029423414,-0.06916641552096867,0.1518882606786481};
INDArray array = Nd4j.create(weight, new int[]{1, 7});
System.out.println(array);
```

The output is

```
[-0.13,  -0.11,  0.11,  -0.02,  0.13,  -0.07,  0.15]
```

The desired output should be

```
[-0.13404223866376802,-0.11294084872465669,0.11232944517596409,-0.01687720880184701,0.13288394029423414,-0.06916641552096867,0.1518882606786481]
```

How convert with full precision ?

Comment: The point behind what @LeoAso is saying is that the INDArray isn't _actually_ truncating your data -- it stores and operates on the entire double. It's just what its toString() method does. His answer allows you to format the INDArray with the precision you want.

Comment: @TheAIArchitect that's interesting. I just used INDArray's `toDoubleMatrix` and checked this. It appears that what I get back is different from the original double[][] used to create the INDArray, starting at the 7th decimal. It appears the data is truncated into a `FloatBuffer`, and when transformed back to `Double[][]`, random junk is added to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
int precision = 7;
String printed = new NDArrayStrings(precision).format(this);
System.out.println(printed);
```

with whatever precision you want. `NDArrayStrings` is in the `org.nd4j.linalg.string` package.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line before creating the INDArray:

```
Nd4j.setDefaultDataTypes(org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.DataType.DOUBLE, org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.DataType.FLOAT16);
```

This will change the default precision Nd4j to Double and Float16.

You can put a static call in your class so you call it once and forget about it.

```
    class Foo {
       static {
          putTheCallHere();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, with latest 0.9.x nd4j:

```
    new NDArrayStrings(15).format(Nd4j.create(new double[]{0.4,0.3}))
    [0.400000005960464,  0.300000011920929]

    Nd4j.create(new double[]{0.4}).getDouble(0)
    0.4000000059604645
```

Edit: now I see the reason, Nd4j only initialize to "float" numbers ...
So only 7 digits are correct, better to use "getFloat"

```
    Nd4j.create(new double[]{0.4 }).getFloat(0)
    0.4
```